# How to generate a package.json file for nodejs/node source code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json

I am analyzing the source code of NodeJs/node to get the typed-ast of each .js files in the source code. However, to achieve this, I need a package.json file to see what libraries it depends on. However the NodeJs/node doesn't contain a package.json file. How should I generate a package.json file or find all the library dependencies for the famous project NodeJs/node? Thank you!

Project meteor also doesn't contain any package.json file, but it contains scripts/dev-bundle-tool-package.js and scripts/dev-bundle-server-package.js files, from which we can easily generate a package.json file. But I haven't seen anything like that in NodeJs/node.

Comment: [check this](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file)

Comment: Node is not a Node.js package, it's the framework. It has no dependencies on npm, all its dependencies are either on the OS, or internal within the project's source code.

Comment: Are you talking about actually looking at node.js source code? If so I don't believe node uses itself as a compiler.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks! That's also what I'm thinking about. So the source code of Node won't have anything like var fs = require("fs"), instead it's going to say var fs = require("internal/fs").

Comment: None of what's `require()`'d in the Node project would belong in a `package.json` file, because all of those dependencies are internal. What I'm saying is a step beyond that though. It doesn't even make sense for the project to _have_ a `package.json` file because it's not a Node package.